# Reporting services instance properties disabled

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence

I am trying to access the reporting server properties in SSMS. But the link seems disabled and cant change any properties in there. Have attached a screenshot. Does anyone have an idea why its disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check that the user running SSMS above has the report server **System Administrator** role.

Check this in Report Manager under **Site Settings** -> **Security**.

[image]

The other thing to note is that by default only the **BUILTIN\Administrators** group has this role. If you have UAC enabled this can cause issues; if you think you are already in this group you have to make sure you're loading SSMS with **Run as Administrator** to prevent any UAC restrictions.